# Backtrack 5 r3 "apt-get upgrade" error [NEED HELP]

Tags: package, apt-get

```
root@bt:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  smartphone-pentest-framework
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up w3af (1.2-bt2) ...
tar: pybloomfiltermmap-0.2.0.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
/var/lib/dpkg/info/w3af.postinst: line 4: cd: pybloomfiltermmap-0.2.0: No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
svn: Working copy 'w3af' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
dpkg: error processing w3af (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 w3af
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root
```

---

I have copied and pasted the errors i get while updating the packing "smartphone-pentest-framework" above.

What is going wrong and what is the problem?

Comment: i am using the command "apt-get upgrade"

Answer (score 4):

As you can see "/var/lib/dpkg/info/w3af.postinst: line 4: cd: pybloomfiltermmap-0.2.0: No such file or directory" so simple solution to change the download URL here is the trick they have a bug in their script as the repository moved to https://svn.code.sf.net/p/w3af/code/trunk
so simply edit w3af.postinst file (vi /var/lib/dpkg/info/w3af.postinst)
and replace old url with
https://svn.code.sf.net/p/w3af/code/trunk
save file and then run w3af setup again...